# How do I avoid update checks for third party software (cobook), dont want to "update" by mistake

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, software-update

I have an app that I bought, unfortunately the company was also bought and the new version is seriously worse.

Hiding is not possible for third party software.
Removing MAS receipt makes the software "damaged".
Setting softwareupdate ignore cobook, does not work either.

There has to be some hack available, I don't want to "update" by mistake, and it bugs me to see the red "1", since I usually keep my software updated.

This would however be a downdate.

Answer (score 2):

The MAS receipt is designed just so you *can't* do that - otherwise you could hand the app to all your friends without them having to buy it ;-)

Did you try telling App Store to "Ignore Updates" - right click in empty space to the right of the App name… though I've heard reports this is no longer working in Yosemite; I've no updates to test on right now.

Comment: OK, so removing the MAS receipt may not be the way to go. But there has to be another way, somehow. It is not possible to right-click anywhere in the update section, from what I've read, Apple has removed that option for third party apps.

In summary, this did not answer the question.

Comment: The answer is,  since the removal of ignore - to just actually ignore it, or see if the app is available in a non-MAS version. BTW, you didn't actually say what OS you were on, so my answer had to cover the bases.